# JavaScript: Pass element to function

Tags: javascript

Lets have following javascript function:

```
function myfunc(elem)
{
   elem.innerHTML="Some text";
}
```

Now I want to call this function on load, inside HTML table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onload="myfunc(this)">

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, this won't work, but you get basic idea. I could use document.getElementById(), but I have big table.

Comment: You should query the DOM and add events with JavaScript, not in the markup.

Comment: When do you want to change the innerHTML? What are the conditions for which cells get their content changed? Only certain elements support onload (and you shouldn't use them as attributes).  Here is a list of elements that support onload: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp  It would be better to have a specific event that triggers content instead of load.

Comment: Elongated version of elclanrs' answer: The old norm was to attach JS functions by setting attributes in the HTML. You still tend to see that when someone is writing a quick example, but in modern coding the preference is to give your important elements ID or class attributes, and then when your JavaScript file sees the document has loaded ('DOMContentLoaded'), add event listeners where appropriate.

Comment: you need a specific action for each <td> element ? or all the same?

Comment: It "doesn't work" because `td` elements don't produce a load event.

Comment: I want to call the same function after the page is loaded for all <td> elements inside that table.

Comment: Just put your script below the `table` or at the bottom of the page, and then select all the `td` elements.

Comment: Have you tried using a `document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("td")` method to get all of the td elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just query for the element on load then pass in the value.
Now if you want to use `document.getElementById()` then just make your TD fields easy to parse in a `for loop` i.e

```
  id="c11", id="c12" ....
```

Where c= cell and 11 is the first cell (first row first col), 12 is the second cell (first row second col)

So in your script tag you can just:

```
  var id;

  for(var i = 0; i < howevermanyRows; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < howevermanyCols; j++){
        id = document.getElementById('c'+i+j);
        // you do the rest

   }
  }
```

obviously you are going to have to set conditions and logic to get this right. But this is the general outline